# Когда Петербург стал Санкт-Петербургом (или он был им с самого начала)?

Tags: история, названия

Сразу прошу прощения, если вопрос неподходящий для этого сайта.

Известно, что с 1991 г. город на Неве называется Санкт-Петербург, до этого с 1924 г. был Ленинградом, а с 1914 по 1924 гг. — Петроградом.

Так вот, я не могу понять, до 1914 г. он был просто Петербургом или Санкт-Петербургом! Всегда считал, что в XIX в. и тем более раньше он был просто Петербургом. Вполне могу допустить, что он в какие-то времена был и Петроградом тоже (в первый раз, до XX в.), но Санкт-Петербургом...

P. S. Если всё-таки этот вопрос неприемлем для этого сайта, напишите мне, пожалуйста, в комментариях, и я удалю его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам Петр называл город на голландский манер "Санкт-Питерсбурх" (город святого Петра), но затем название онемечилось (Санкт-Петербург). В 1914 в связи с войной против немцев город получил руссифицированное наименование Петроград, а в 1924 после смерти В. И. Ленина, город назвали в его честь Ленинградом. В 1991 городу вернули прежнее имя Санкт-Петербург. Так как подобное длинное наименование не удобно для большинства русскоговорящих, то как до революции, так и сегодня используются сокращенные названия Петербург и Питер.

Comment: "Петербург" и "Питер" - наименования далеко не равноценные. "Питер" в Петербурге считается вульгаризмом, как и сравнительно поздно появившиеся в устной речи "васька"  (Васильевский остров) или "гостинка" (станция метро "Гостиный двор"), с квази-московскими топонимическими суффиксами. Один из самых мелких аргументов, отрицающих литературное значение слова "питер" : от него можно образовать слово "питерец", но нельзя сделать подобного в женском роде (никто не пытается произнести неуклюжее "питерка")..

Comment: Спасибо, Марк! Однако в Википедии написано, что Питером город называют и сами жители. Конечно, Вы можете сказать, что она врёт, и, может быть, будете даже правы, не знаю...

Comment: Я нигде не утверждал равноценность "Петербург" и "Питер", а лишь констатировал факт их использования. О том, что "Питер" используют и петербуржцы, говорит хотя бы недавняя песня С. Шнурова "В Питере пить".

Answer (score 0):

Официальное название с момента основания - Санкт-Петербург.
Петербург - укороченная форма.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3

Comment: Спасибо, Морковкин!